# How can i easily keep libraries up to date for PHP app?

Tags: javascript, php, automation, build-automation

Typically when I want to update a script before releasing it I have to manually grab the latest copies of jquery, jqueryui, datatables, etc and then move them all to the script location.

Is there an automated way to do this? I was looking at gulp to possibly do this but wasn't sure whats best. I do not currently use node.js so I don't have npm.

Comment: Take a look at composer. https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using bower http://bower.io/

if you want to update your php libraries, take a look at https://getcomposer.org/

Comment: The only thing I warn you is to care with updates. Some libraries can break your application. Always test many times before deploy in production, principally if the lib isn't tested by it's vendor. Another thing that can make you application break is incompatibility, cause this you must always test all functionalities exhaustively.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is exactly what I was looking for its also a lot easier to sue than composer.